# how to select max of row number data in a table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this,

```
|   ID  |   Client  |   Some_Value  |   Row_No  |
|   1   |   HP      |   123         |   1   |
|   1   |   HP      |   1245        |   2   |
|   1   |   Dell    |   123445      |   3   |
|   2   |   HP      |   111         |   1   |
|   2   |   HP      |   223         |   2   |
|   3   |   Dell    |   34          |   1   |
|   3   |   Dell    |   5563        |   2   |
```

---

And i need output like this ,

```
|   ID  |   Client  |   Some_Value  |   Row_No  |
|   1   |   Dell    |   123445      |   3       |
|   2   |   HP      |   223         |   2       |
|   3   |   Dell    |   5563        |   2       |
```

---

Please consider that I'm a beginner and explain me the logic.

Comment: use max() function in your query

Comment: Why is `Dell` in the resut for `ID = 1`. Because in the example there is `HP` twice and `Dell` once for `ID = 1`

Comment: I have one more doubt ,related to the same data input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE **Row_NUMBER()** and **Partition BY**:

```
;With T AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Client,
        Some_Value,
        Row_No,
        Row_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY ID Order BY Row_No Desc) AS PartNo
    FROM TableName
)
SELECT
    ID,
    Client,
    Some_Value,
    Row_No
FROM T
WHERE T.PartNo=1
```

Update Statement Example:

```
;With T AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Client,
        Some_Value,
        Row_No,
        Row_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY ID Order BY Row_No Desc) AS PartNo
    FROM TableName
)
Update TableName
SET Name=T.Name
FROM T
WHERE T.PartNo=1 
AND TableName.Id=T.Id
```

Comment: Thank You . And now can you tell me how can i update that max row number data to another table using "ID" in the where condition ?

Comment: ;With Query is a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. So you can also write update instead select